# Cant start docker `OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/usr/local/bin/docker-credential-ecr-login'`

Tags: python-3.x, macos, docker, docker-compose

I want to start my docker-compose and I always get this error.

Docker Desktop tells me I'm logged in. I also rebooted once and logged in again.
I don't quite understand why that's not possible. If I pull other Docker Containers in another project, everything works.
We dont use paython in our project.

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b
$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.25.4, build 8d51620a
$ python --version
Python 3.7.4

macOS Catalina 10.15.3
```

Here is the stacktrace

```
> docker-compose up
Pulling mongo (mongo:latest)...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/docker/credentials/store.py", line 80, in _execute
  File "subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
  File "subprocess.py", line 488, in run
  File "subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/usr/local/bin/docker-credential-ecr-login'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 264, in _resolve_authconfig_credstore
  File "site-packages/docker/credentials/store.py", line 35, in get
  File "site-packages/docker/credentials/store.py", line 104, in _execute
docker.credentials.errors.StoreError: Unexpected OS error "Exec format error", errno=8

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 72, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 128, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1077, in up
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1073, in up
  File "compose/project.py", line 548, in up
  File "compose/service.py", line 361, in ensure_image_exists
  File "compose/service.py", line 1250, in pull
  File "compose/progress_stream.py", line 102, in get_digest_from_pull
  File "compose/service.py", line 1215, in _do_pull
  File "site-packages/docker/api/image.py", line 396, in pull
  File "site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 48, in get_config_header
  File "site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 324, in resolve_authconfig
  File "site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 235, in resolve_authconfig
  File "site-packages/docker/auth.py", line 281, in _resolve_authconfig_credstore
docker.errors.DockerException: Credentials store error: StoreError('Unexpected OS error "Exec format error", errno=8')
[52557] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

Answer (score 0):

resetting the docker in docker-hub/settings solved the problem.